# Aggregate Where on multiple select query sql

Tags: sql

So I am using this query to count the the number of authentication errors in my database :

```
SELECT  (
SELECT COUNT(audit.server_response_code)
FROM   audit Where audit.server_response_code = '401' 
) AS Locked,
(
SELECT COUNT(audit.server_response_code)
FROM   audit Where audit.server_response_code = '403' 
) AS unlocked,
(
SELECT COUNT(audit.server_response_code)
FROM   audit Where audit.server_response_code = '490' 
) AS Passforget,
(
Select Count (audit.server_response_code)
From audit where audit.server_response_code = '491' 
) AS invalid
```

The query is working fine , however i want to add an aggregate where statement that applies on the four statements.How can i do it?

Comment: You can add a `WHERE` to the outer `SELECT` - is that what you mean?

Comment: i tried using where at the outer select statement but it gave me an error stating that a from clause is missing , i used a from clause but it didnt work

Comment: Look at the `filter()` clause for aggregates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select count(case when audit.server_response_code = '401' then 1 end) AS Locked,
       count(case when audit.server_response_code = '403' then 1 end) AS unlocked,
       count(case when audit.server_response_code = '490' then 1 end) AS Passforget,
       count(case when audit.server_response_code = '491' then 1 end) AS invalid 
from audit
where audit.server_response_code in ('401','403','490','491')
```

The `WHERE` clause is perhaps not needed, but may speed things up (depending on data and indexes.)

**UPDATE:** As requested "i want to add a sum column that sums all the counts but its now working , how can i do it?"

```
select count(case when audit.server_response_code = '401' then 1 end) AS Locked,
       count(case when audit.server_response_code = '403' then 1 end) AS unlocked,
       count(case when audit.server_response_code = '490' then 1 end) AS Passforget,
       count(case when audit.server_response_code = '491' then 1 end) AS invalid, 
       count(*) as total_count
from audit
where audit.server_response_code in ('401','403','490','491')
```

Comment: i want to add a sum column that sums all the counts but its now working , how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

Simplify your logic!

```
select sum(case when a.server_response_code = '401' then 1 else 0 end) as locked,
       sum(case when a.server_response_code = '403' then 1 else 0 end) as unlocked,
       sum(case when a.server_response_code = '490' then 1 else 0 end) as Passforget,
       sum(case when a.server_response_code = '491' then 1 else 0 end) as Invalid
from audit a;
```

With this structure you can readily add a `group by`.

Or, an even simpler method is to put the values in different rows:

```
select a.server_response_code, count(*)
from audit a
group by a.server_response_code;
```

Note:  I haven't filtered for the four codes that you mention.  If there are other codes, you can add that filter.